# Specify jvm options in a configuration file

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to add `-Xss40m` to a configuration file inside a project itself. I don't want to create the configuration file for a particular IDE, I want it to be inside the project directory itself.

Is it possible?

Comment: For the guy who voted it to close as ***needs more clarity***. What clarity do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah so this can be done through gradle for example, but without seeing how you're executing code or what tools you're using it's hard to help. This is one example though.

### Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'application'

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
        "-Xss40m"
]
```

Executing the run task of gradle will allow the application, in any development environment, to run with the jvm arguments provided.

### Maven

Create a file, if it doesn't exist, called jvm.config in the .mvn directory in your projects parent directory. The options provided will be supplied with the JVM. It should be noted that all options should be separated by a space, however in your case there is only one option.

File

```
/<myProject>/.mvn/jvm.config
```

File Content

```
-Xss50m
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am using maven, do you know how to achieve the same when using maven?

Comment: Yeah so this is possible with Maven, the following link will do a much better job than I can in the short space available but I will update the post with a maven alternative; http://maven.apache.org/configure.html